# Chef reference to cookbook_name in attributes/default.rb

Tags: chef-infra

I am trying to the following in chef in `attributes/default.rb`:

```
default[cookbook_name.to_s]["foo"] = bar
```

However, I can not seem to get the cookbook name in default attributes file. Is it even possible to get the cookbook name in the attributes file?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not supported. You'll have to use a normal string.

Comment: Nope, would have said if there was.